# copy to clipboard on a vim installed with '-clipboard' on a server with no sudo access

Tags: vim, clipboard

I want be able to copy to the system clipboard on vim. I want to just add the following code.

```
vnoremap <C-c> "*y  //to my .vimrc
```

However my version of vim was installed with '-clipboard' and :echo has('clipboard') returns 0. some desktop systems ship Vim without the +clipboard feature, which is the case on my distribution. Also I don't have sudo access to reinstall a new distro. I have been searching around the web for a solution with no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't expect wonders with that setup, so here are some workarounds:

As long as the system has the tools to *compile* your own Vim (or if you have a separate, similar such system), you can easily compile Vim and install it to your *local user's directory* (or anywhere else you have access to); this is just an option to `./configure`.

If you just need to transfer short snippets of text (which is all visible in the Vim window), you can use the terminal's copy-and-paste (with the appropriate empty value setting of `'mouse'`, and probably `'number'` turned off to avoid grabbing that, too).

For larger text, you can `:[range]write` the lines to a temporary file, and access that elsewhere, or use a command-line tool like `xsel` or `xclip` to transfer the contents to the clipboard, with `:w !xsel --clipboard` even from within Vim.